# Django/JS: ChoiceField for >1000 items

Tags: javascript, django, django-forms, webui

I'm creating a sample project in Django.
User has to choose an item from an existing list, this list has >10000 items.
To start with,

- Prefilled list like this: https://leaverou.github.io/awesomplete/ .
- Dinamically filled list (after keyrelease event), via ajax query after keyrelease event, without csrf_form.
- One field to search for the item, and another field to actually hold the pk.

What way is better?
Any suggestions?
Any framework to do this?

Comment: Celery ... try it !

Comment: `django-autocomplete-light` would seem to fit the bill for what you're trying to do, and it is widely used. https://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/